# Why is this object null after being assigned?

Tags: c#, null, pass-by-reference

Full class here: https://gist.github.com/archer884/453c9937afa2dcb74f24

In my class (a tree of some kind), I have a `Node<T> _root;`

In the Add method, this variable is assigned to a local variable called simply `node`, and then we do a bit of work on `node`, included below.

```
while (node != null)
{
    nodeDimensions = Dimensions(node.Item);
    if (dimensions.SequenceEqual(nodeDimensions))
        throw new ArgumentException("An element with the same key already exists in the tree.");

    dimension = depth % dimensions.Count;
    comparison = dimensions[dimension].CompareTo(nodeDimensions[dimension]);

    if (comparison <= 0)
    {
        node = node.LeftChild;
        continue;
    }
    else
    {
        node = node.RightChild;
        continue;
    }
}
node = new KdTreeNode<TItem>(item);
```

So, to me, this looks like I'm just assigning the Easter eggs out of that variable, but my test case does not agree: `Assert.NotNull(tree.Root);` always fails.

Edit: For future readers, I will note that the following worked.

```
if (_root == null)
{
    _root = new KdTreeNode<TItem>(item);
    return;
}
```

This way _root doesn't refer to null when we start assigning things. I think. Maybe one of these other guys will clarify.

Comment: You need to actually assign it back to `_root` (or whatever the parent node should be.) Even though you've assigned `node = _root` near the top of the method, that only means that `node` now references the same object (if any) as `_root`. Changing the properties of that reference will be reflected in `_root`, but *changing the object to which `node` refers* will have no effect whatsoever on `_root`.

Comment: [Censored.] [Other various, frustrated words.] Ok.

Answer (score 0):

At no point in the code is the `_root` field actually assigned to hence `tree.Root` will always be `null`.  You need to assign `_root` to the value that is calculated in `Add`

Comment: Does that work differently if _root has a value first?

Comment: @archer884 yes but at no point in the code is `_root` ever assigned a value.  Note the new `node` you create is also never put into the tree so it won't actually grow either